# What does passing an argument to .toString() do?

Tags: javascript

I do not understand what `.toString(16)` does in this code -

```
var fade = function (node) {
    var level = 1;

    var step = function () {
        var hex = level.toString(16); // ← This part
        node.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFF' + hex + hex;

        if (level < 15) {
            level += 1;
            setTimeout(step, 100);
        }
    };

    setTimeout(step, 100);
};

fade(document.body);
```

Comment: Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `level.toString(16)` is converting a number, `level`, into its hexadecimal representation. The number in `toString` is the [radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString).

Answer (score 1):

`level.toString(16)` takes the number in `level` and converts it to the string, using the base specified by the first parameter.

Converting a number to a string representation in base 16 effectively becomes the hexadecimal version of the number.

More here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString